# The argument type 'DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey THere i am working with dropdownmenitem but in items i am getting an error that says The argument type 'DropdownMenuItem' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'. Any idea whats wrong ?

```
class _chatscreenState extends State<chatscreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Chat'),actions: [DropdownButton(items: DropdownMenuItem(child: Row(children: [Icon(Icons.exit_to_app,),SizedBox(height: 8,),Text('Logout')],),),value: 'Logout', ],),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats/EhXksd48J0ylTPpPb8ZM/messages')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>? snapshot) {
          if (snapshot!.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('Hey'));
          }
          final documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
              child: Text(documents[index]['Text']),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/EhXksd48J0ylTPpPb8ZM/messages')
              .add({'Text': 'Hey Again '});
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove DropdownButton from your code

```
List list = ["Button 1", "Button 2"];

actions: [
      DropdownButton(
        onChanged: (val){},
          items: list.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: e,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.exit_to_app,color: Colors.black,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(e)
          ],
        ),
      )).toList())
    ],
```

Comment: that doesnt create the dopdown menu item as i may create more items . How do i create a dropdown menu item here ?

Comment: check updated answer